# Dodge geom_points based on only a single grouping variable when there are multiple grouping variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point, aesthetics, position-dodge

I am having an issue with trying to dodge points only by the color aesthetic when I am also using another aesthetic for shape. When I add the option to dodge, it dodges the points such that each shape+color option is dodged. Is there a way to specify the dodge such that a single aesthetic is being dodged? The only way I can think is to have two datasets for two separate geom_point's where the shape is manually set but unsure how that might work with the legend.

[image: Geom_point with color and shape aesthetics being dodged]

Example code

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x = c,y = Mean,color = Group,shape = Interval)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge2(width = 0.5)) +
  labs(y = "Item Average") +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Tried to specify a group aesthetic within geom_point function itself that would use only that to dodge the points by Group.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Maybe try `group=Group` in your `aes()`

Comment: @markhogue yes, if you delete your comments I can delete mine too. Keeps the answer tidier. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `position_dodge` instead of `position_dodge2`, and use `group = Group` inside `aes` to get the points dodging according to the same variable as color:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = c, y = Mean, color = Group, shape = Interval)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = Group), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
             size = 3) +
  labs(y = "Item Average") +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Or, to dodge by the same variable as shape, use `group = Interval`

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = c, y = Mean, color = Group, shape = Interval)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = Interval), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
             size = 3) +
  labs(y = "Item Average") +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

If I might make a suggestion, your plot might be easier to understand if you did:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Interval, y = Mean, color = Group)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Group)) +
  labs(y = "Item Average") +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data inferred from plot in picture**

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  c = "View1",
  Mean = c(3.91, 3.96, 4, 4.07, 4.14, 4.29),
  Group = factor(c("No Coach", "No Coach", "Email","Coach", "Coach", "Email"),
                 levels = c("Email", "Coach", "No Coach")),
  Interval = factor(c("Post", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Post"), 
                    levels = c("Pre", "Post"))
)
```